# Clicks inside tableau iframe don't trigger activity in idle-vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, events, iframe, tableau-api

I have a vue website that logs users out when they have been inactive for 45 minutes. I am using idle-vue (docs [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/idle-vue)). This is my code (I include this is main.js and use the 'onIdle' event hook to log the user out):

```
import IdleVue from 'idle-vue'
import Vue from 'vue'

let options = {
  idleTime: 1000 * 60 * 45, // sign out after 45 minutes of inactivity
  startAtIdle: false,
  eventEmitter: Vue.prototype.$bus,
  events: ['keydown', 'mousedown', 'touchstart', 'scroll'],
}

Vue.use(IdleVue, options)
```

This works great for the most part, but a good portion of my website is iframes (tableau embedded views) and events inside these iframes don't count as activity on the website. So if a user is working inside an embedded view for 45 mins, it will log them out in the middle of working. Is there a way I can capture an event from inside an iframe and use it to trigger activity?

For testing I used these event hooks in main.js and set my inactivity time to 5 seconds instead of 45 mins:

```
onIdle () {
  console.log('Idle')
},
onActive () {
  console.log('Active')
}
```

I also found [these](https://help.tableau.com/current/api/embedding_api/en-us/docs/embedding_api_event.html) Tableau docs, so I tried adding events like 'MarkSelectionChanged' or 'filterchanged' to the 'events' list in my idle-vue configuration, but that didn't work. Does anyone know how I can capture activity in a tableau embedded view and register it as activity? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Yogi both great ideas. I'll try them out, thank you!